# What transitions assembly into actually executable material?

Tags: c++, compilation

What I know about compilers, is that they translate source code into assembly, then  magically turn that assembly into an executable.

How do they turn assembly into an executable? Any links would be apreciated, as I want to make my own compiler in C++.

Comment: Please check this link https://cs.lmu.edu/~ray/notes/asmtoexe/

Comment: The *assembler* and the *linker*.

Comment: For a project, it might be easier to have your compiler generate Java byte code, and execute the result in a JVM.

Comment: _What I know about compilers, is they translate source code into assembly_ This is only one option (which I believe was used in old C compilers). Modern compilers skip the assembly step and just compile binary code out of the AST (or whatever is the preceding intermediate representation). AFAIK... ;-)

Comment: A compiler can also translate directly to machine code, or to some other programming language - some custom language, or even a "normal" one like C.

Comment: `clang` is a reasonably modern open-source compiler, with pretty decent documentation available. It compiles to `llvm`, not assembly. Check it out; `clang` is also written in c++.

Comment: Ahhhh. Thank you for this, helps me out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To turn assembly language into an executable you first use an assembler, and then (usually) a linker.

An assembler will take assembly language source code and (usually) produce an object file in some format or other (e.g., COFF or ELF). The exact details vary with the instruction set, but a typical processor will have a table (or more than one) showing how instructions for that processor are encoded. The assembler parses the instructions, then uses the information from the encoding table to tell it how to generate words that encode those instructions.

The linker then takes that object file, at least potentially combines it with others containing external routines it used but didn't define, and produces an executable. Again, the details vary, but in this case the variation is mostly based on the formats of the files involved. At one time most linkers produced static executables, so any external function used by the program required the linker to copy that function into the executable. Most modern OSes/loaders support some form of dynamic linking, where a program can depend on external routines that are not copied statically into the program--rather, the program typically contains a reference to the names of the file and the function, and it's up to the OS's loader to find the file at load time, assign an address to each function, and fix up the references to point to the address assigned to the code.

Comment: Thank you for this post, this has answered my question.

Answer (score 1):

You would use "an assembler" for that. With MSVC compiler suite there is [MASM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/assembler/masm/microsoft-macro-assembler-reference?view=vs-2019) for example. You should note that, usually, you don't actually get *assembly language* output files on disk during a normal compile and link.